# BinaryWriter/Reader - Getting unexpected readbacks

Tags: c#, types, binary

Put simply, I'm having trouble writing a binary file, then reading back that same file. This is a settings file, which contains a few strings and an int. I have no problem with writing the strings, but when I get to the int I just can't get a value back when the settings are read.

A little back story: I'm more of a c/c++ programmer, c# isn't totally foreign, but it's not my forte. For instance, I had no idea if I wrote a string, it takes care of the length and reads for you.. just.  `x.ReadString()`. Neat.

Here's some rough code to give you an idea of what I'm doing. Note this is stripped of error checking, and most of the superfluous reads/writes. Just kept it to bare minimal:

```
public static int LDAPport;
public static string Username;
public static char Ver;

public static int LoadSettings()
    {
            using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(File.Open("data\\Settings.cfg", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                char cin = r.ReadChar();
                if (cin != Ver)
                {
                    // Corrupted or older style settings
                    return 1;
                }
                Username = r.ReadString();
                LDAPport = r.ReadInt32();
                r.Close();
            }
    return 0;
    }

    public static bool SaveSettings()

            using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("data\\Settings.cfg", FileMode.Create)))
            {
                w.Write(Ver);   
                w.Write(Username);
                w.Write(LDAPport);
                w.Close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So when it writes 389 (I've verified it is getting the proper value when it goes to write) When read back, LDAPport gets -65145. Which tells me it's either not reading all 4 bytes for an int (it's 4 isn't it?), or it's reading a number that's unsigned (since I'm expecting signed). Casting seemed to do nothing for me.

I've also tried other read methods. .Read() does the same thing, I've tried changing the data type for the number, including UInt32 to no avail. Everything I've read just says simply .Write(389) then .Read()! that simple!.. well no. There doesn't seem to be a method for just int.. I assume it's got those smarts in .Read() yes?

Can someone with a c# brain greater than mine shed some light as to what's going on here? Or has my brain officially turned to jelly at this point? :)

Comment: serialization might be better suited for what you are doing

Comment: Just as a C# FYI, your `r.Close();` and `w.Close();` statements are superfluous, as exiting the `using` block calls `Dispose()` on them, which closes them if open.  And I agree with @Plutonix that letting .NET serialize and deserialize this stuff for you is pretty nice.

Comment: What is the datatype of the variable Ver?

Comment: Sounds to me you are conflating types.  Is "Ver" *really* a Char?   Pretty unusual choice for a type to store a version number.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yes, Ver is a char. The version number is used more as a key to verify the file isn't corrupted in some way.

Comment: @John Saunders: My bad. Thing wouldn't let me submit without tags.. I'm all.. okay okay here!

Comment: Tags are good - they belong in the tags line, not in your title.

Comment: If Ver is a char then I can't reproduce your problem. The two methods work just fine. Perhaps you have some other read/write mismatch.

Comment: @Steve : perhaps I'll get up and walk around and take another look with a slightly fresher brain. Been stalled on this for far longer than I'd care to admit :)

Comment: The correct answer seems to be the latter: your brain has officially turned to jelly at this point. :p

Comment: Post the definition of all fields/properties of `this` in this code snippet. You've got a type mismatch causing you to reinterpret bytes. I also encourage you to look into a higher-level serialization format such as XmlSerializer or protobuf. You waste 10-100x performance but it does not matter.

Comment: @usr: I feel like an idiot not fully understanding what you're asking me. All of this code is contained in a class. If I type "this." anywhere in my code including the above it (visual studio) tells me it doesn't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: OK, post the definition of Ver, Username, LDAPport so that we can see their types. You must be writing a different type than you are reading. That gives you the same bytes reinterpreted as different values.

Comment: I was wondering if that's what you were driving at. C Background :). I'll add them above shortly. Actually I'm honing in on it. I broke out the offending read by reading individual bytes, see what's going on at the binary level. It seems I'm writing an integer (0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1000 0111) but appear to be getting back (1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0001 1000 0111). The two final bytes line up. Is this unsigned? I forget how that works

Comment: (Oh, and the above binary is supposed to be 391, just happened to be the number I tested with at the time)

Comment: Thinking out loud, is this some sort of integer overflow issue? -65145 - 389 = -65534, which is suspiciously close to the inverse of `ushort.MaxValue`. I've not considered how this could be arrived at yet - will do so now!

Comment: Why is the binary supposed to be 391? You wrote in your question your port value is 389. Note that a 16-bit -391 is 0xfe79, which interpreted as unsigned is 65145. Likewise, 32-bit -65145 is 0xffff0187, while 0x0187 is 391. That hardly seems like that could just be a coincidence. But the code you posted wouldn't do that, so the code you posted isn't the code that's executing. You need to post a complete, minimal code example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The only thing different is a try statement around the using statements as well as a couple more strings. For good measure, I've moved the int read higher up so it's one of the first written/read. same thing. 391, as I said was just what I was using in that instant. I did indeed start with 389 but that's why I made the distinction.

Comment: So I guess we can safely say it's another factor. Other people are saying that they've tried the code and it works. I agree, it must be elsewhere. There's too much to post here, so I guess I'm left to my own devices. Thanks for the help everyone, I appreciate it. I'll leave this open for the night in case someone gets a spark of brilliance in the meantime.